# Ripple effect is firing on scroll

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

I'm getting the ripple effect to fire on touch (scroll) and not on click like it should be (guessing). This is happening either on `ion-ripple-effect` tag or in an ionic tag that has the ripple effect by default (like `ion-item`).

Here is a snippet of my code using the `ion-ripple-effect tag`:

```
<ion-row class="dash ion-margin-top">
  <ion-col size-xs="6" size-sm="4" size-md="3" *ngFor="let item of dash">
    <div class="box shadow">
      <div class="content ion-activatable" routerLink="{{item.route}}">
        <ion-icon name="{{ item.icon }}" color="primary"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label color="dark">{{ item.name }}</ion-label>
        <ion-ripple-effect></ion-ripple-effect>
       </div>
    </div>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Does anyone have encountered this, and if so, knows who to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am seeing a problem here as well, but only on iOS. I have a list of ion-item and when scrolling there are visible gaps in the list and other visible glitches. Removing ion-ripple-effect eliminates the problem, but no ripple effect anymore. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I didn't find any solution, sorry.

Comment: It seems that the bug is tracked here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/22030 and here https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/22030